# Is there any way of introducing a functional form on an input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm pretty new at python and programming, and I was trying to make a code that calculates the integral of some function on an interval [a,b]. On my class notes (I'm studying physics, so all my notes are related to this kind of things), there's a method called Simpson's Rule which provides a pretty accurate result of the integral. At the start of my code, I define the function I want to integrate like this:

```
def f(x):
    return x**3-3*x**2-x+3
```

Then, I define another function which calculates the result of the integral with the Simpson's formula of my notes.

I also have, at the beggining of the script, two imputs to get the integrating interval:

```
a=float(input("Start of the interval: "))
b=float(input("End of the interval: "))
```

My question is if there's a way to get the function you want to integrate from an input, and then use that input to create the function **f(x)** that I define at the start. The goal is making the program work for every function without changing anything in the code, and just running the script without having to change things inside the code everytime I change the function I want to integrate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're talking about. Can you give an example of how you'd like your program to behave (input and output)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want a lambda. A lambda is a function defined at runtime so you can do something like this

```
def f(n):
    nf = float(n)
    return lambda y:nf + y

functions = []
for i in range(2):
    functions.append( f( input("x ") ) )

y = float(input("y "))
for fn in functions:
    print(fn(y))
```

what that does is return you a set of functions for each f(n) that you can then call with another input paramter if you like.  `lambda x,y:nf + y * x` if you needed 2 input paramters or `lambda :fn * 3` if you needed no parameters.